# actionscript 3 wall hit-detection

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

Am making a simple flash game and am trying to keep the avatar from hitting walls in a given level, here is the code I wrote, its simple enough

```
       var hitWall:Boolean = checkWallHitlvl1();



        if ( downKeyIsBeingPressed  )
            {
                avatar.moveABit( 0, 1 );
                if(hitWall)
                {
                    avatar.moveABit( 0, -5);

                }

            }
            else if ( upKeyIsBeingPressed  )
            {
                avatar.moveABit( 0, -1 );
                if(hitWall)
                {
                    avatar.moveABit( 0, 5 );

                }

            }   
            else if ( leftKeyIsBeingPressed  )
            {
                avatar.moveABit( -1, 0 );
                if(hitWall)
                {

                    avatar.moveABit( 5, 0 );


                }

            }
            else if ( rightKeyIsBeingPressed )
            {
                avatar.moveABit( 1, 0 );
                if(hitWall)
                {
                    avatar.moveABit( -5, 0 );

                }

            }
```

hitWall checks if the avatar hits the level's walls, the problem with this code is that even if for say I hit a wall from the right, and am trying to move left, I cant since hitWall doesn't check from where the wall is hit, my question is is there a way to make this work without actually needing to figure out from which direction the player hits a given wall, i tried moving the avatar automatically to the left if he hits it from the right, but it didn't quite work out so well...

any suggestions please?

thanx =D

**EDIT1:** i edited the code, it works now, but it looks kinda jerky since i have to step backwards 5 pixels, I cannot step backwards 1 pixel unfortunately since, since flash's hitTestObject still returns true (checkWallHitLvl1() basically uses hitTestObject to check if the player hits the wall), any suggestions?

**EDIT2:** i found a way to fix it, just need to run some more tests and make sure it works fine, if they all pass i will post the code up, basically I just used 4 boolean variables to check which direction i hit the wall, and went from there...=D

Comment: You code is flawed. The move happens then the test runs if it fails your test then no more moving. The flaw here is that the move happened then the test so the avatar is already in the wall. you need to move first then test if fail move it back.

Comment: I will check this out and see if it works out, thanks for the advice =D

Comment: it worked, but its not as smooth as i expected, you see even if i go a step backwards after hitting a wall, actionscrtipt's hitTestObject still returns true, so i had to go backwards like 5 steps for it to work and even then its kinda jerky and doesnt look so smooth...any other suggestions??

thanks for the advice though =)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What I do is keep the position of when it is not hit.

```
    if ( downKeyIsBeingPressed  )
        {
            avatar.moveABit( 0, 1 );
            if(hitWall)
            {
                avatar.moveTo(safeX, safeY);

            } else {
                safeX = x;
                safeY = y;
        }
```

Comment: thats actually pretty good, I did something similar to that in my fix but this is simpler...I think it should work just fine, thanx m8 =)

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use Flixel (www.flixel.org) for this; it's a nice lightweight Actionscript library that handles this sort of thing for you, or if you want to handle the collisions yourself it gives you hitFromLeft(), hitFromRight(), etc. (I might have the function names for those wrong, but you get the idea.)

Answer (score 0):

You can get stage coordinates of the wall with `localToGlobal` (taking center point, for example) and compare direction from avatar center to this point before test. What to do with this value - this depends on your walls' shape. If they're square, just bump player in opposite direction a little. If they're long, or maybe concave... do the math, or even redesign the walls to simplify things.